# Horizontally Stretch in Wrap Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm to have 2 columns of controls when the resolution can fit it but if the resolution gets small enough I'm trying to dynamically resize into one column. A wrap panel works great for this except for the fact that my controls in both my columns aren't stretching across the screen. I've heard of diff ways like creating a custom control (UniformWrapGrid for example) but had no luck. What is the best approach to handle this? Thanks for any advice to point me in the right direction

```
 <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

      <Grid x:Name="GridOne"> <!-- My controls (One Column) --> </Grid>

      <Grid x:Name="GridTwo"> <!-- Some more controls (One column) --> </Grid>

 </WrapPanel>
```

What I've Tried: (This works for the 1st column but the second column stretches horizontally on a new row instead of the second column of the first row)

```
public class UniformWrapPanel : WrapPanel
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double rowY = 0;
        int col = 0;
        double currentRowHeight = 0;

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            var initialSize = child.DesiredSize;
            double columnSize = constrainedSize.Width / 2;
            int colspan = (int)Math.Ceiling(initialSize.Width / columnSize);
            Console.WriteLine(colspan);
            double width = colspan * columnSize;



            if (col > 0 && (col * columnSize) + width > constrainedSize.Width)
            {
                rowY += currentRowHeight;
                col = 0;
                currentRowHeight = 0;
            }


            var childRect = new Rect(col * columnSize, rowY, width, initialSize.Height);
            child.Arrange(childRect);
            currentRowHeight = Math.Max(currentRowHeight, initialSize.Height);
            col += colspan;
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    Size constrainedSize;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        constrainedSize = constraint;
        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
```

Comment: I cant see where you may have an issue, however there is a similar solution here. it might give you a hint. http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/43801.aspx

Comment: That is a good start. Thanks

Comment: Can't really visualize or issue, so a screen shot of what you're seeing might help. However it may be as simple as like `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`